# Create a launcher to launch multiple applications at once?

Tags: launcher, xampp, sublime-text

When I develop, I have to start XAMPP and open up Sublime Text. So, wouldn't it be better to have them both open from the same launcher on my desktop?

Right now I have 2 launchers, one for starting XAMPP (`gksu /opt/lampp/xampp start`), and one for Sublime Text (`gksu /etc/sublime-text/sublime_text`).

Is there a way to combine the 2 into one launcher that starts them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script which launches both, and create a launcher for this script ?

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu /opt/lampp/xampp start
gksu /etc/sublime-text/sublime_text
```

Place this in a shell script, let's say `mydevscript.sh`, and give it execution permissions :

```
chmod +x ./mydevscript.sh
```

Now, when you run it with `./mydevscript.sh`, both commands in it will be executed. Under GNOME, you'll just have to use `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new .` to create a launcher. Choose a name, an icon and a description. The "command" parameter is the absolute path to your script, you can find it using the Browse button.

Comment: I'm pretty new to using Linux, so forgive me if this sound noobish, but how exactly would I accomplish this? I'm not sure how to write a script for Linux.

Comment: Editing my answer.

Comment: Added some explanation. You're welcome ;)